# The program 'makemap' can be found in the following packages: * opensmtpd * sendmail-bin Try: apt install <selected package>

Tags: linux, bash, hashmap, gmail

The program 'makemap' can be found in the following packages:

- opensmtpd
- sendmail-bin
  Try: apt install

I tried using the command apt install opensmtpd and sendmail-bin, but it is still showing error

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you use your admin account for installation? E.g. in Ubuntu did you prefix with `sudo`? You probably need to either `sudo apt install opensmtpd` or `sudo apt install sendmail-bin`. 

If that does not help, please add more information, e.g. what is the exact error message. What is your operation system.

Comment: I am currently using ubuntu system to configure gmail to a ubuntu server, but i cant